# Find the maximum value in column B per unique value in column A

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, array-formulas

e.g. for data

```
___   A   B
  1 cat   5
  2 cat   7
  3 cat   3
  4 dog  10
  5 dog   4
  6 dog   7
```

formula(`cat`) is `7`, formula(`dog`) is `10`.

I'm working in Google Sheets, but would prefer answers that are more generally applicable.

Comment: There are two votes to close as unclear; how can i clarify the question?

Answer (score 5):

A PivotTable with `A` for ROWS and MAX of `B` for Sigma VALUES.

Comment: This looks like it is probably the right answer in some sense, but is not, as presented, complete enough to be useful. (A link to a good how-to for pivot tables would probably fix that.)

Comment: I originally didn't specify which application because i am totally new to spreadsheets and expected there would be commonality of answers. (I wouldn't ask for a general how to, but neither was the answer provided complete. I'd prefer a compelte answer, but a vague hint and a link to how to turn that into a complete answer would do.) I have done research but a starting point has not been easy to find; thus the very specific question about how to do a particular thing, which led to a not very specific but apparently correct answer, and a couple of specific but maybe less right answers. *shrug*

Comment: Obviously there are, but this seemed like a simple enough thing that I would have expected there to be some common ground for an answer. As for including a tag, unfortunately there are a limit of 5 tags per question. As I don't understand the problem space -- which is why i have such a basic question -- i don't know which tags above are more or less relevant than others. But I will pick at random, if that's better.

Comment: Hm. I don't think i did.  i think someone else edited it to add tag "excel". I may be wrong; it was asked a long time ago and i know of no way to see the history of edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89861/discussion-between-vynce-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for a pseudo-MAXIF function. While there is none available natively, one can be constructed in a number of ways.

[image: MAXIF function]

As a standard formula (as in F3 of the image above),

`=MAX(INDEX((A$1:A$6=D3)*B$1:B$6, , ))`

Or as an *array* formula (as in E3 of the image above),

`=MAX(IF(A$1:A$6=D3,B$1:B$6))`

*Array* formulas require <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Once entered correctly, either of the formulas could be filled down for additional `MAXIF` criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use two array formulas:

1. `{=MAX(IF(A1:A6="cat",B1:B6))}` # Returns 7
2. `{=MAX(IF(A1:A6="dog",B1:B6))}` # Returns 10

As noted, array formulas require require you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

besides already provided solutions, if you were looking for an automatically updated formula based on your current autofilter state, you can always use a [subtotal](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) for MAX:

```
=SUBTOTAL(104, B1:B6)
```